# AutoUpdate app in Android 9 throws error while parsing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, auto-update, android-9.0-pie

I am trying to update my app from outside Google Play, but I have an error, I have looked at everything and I cannot find a solution.

With the following 3 methods I hope to do the AutoUpdate:

```
private final String FILE_NAME = "app-release.apk";

public void checkStoragePermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 123);
        } else {
            updateApp();}
    }

private void updateApp() {
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/" + FILE_NAME));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 123: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                updateApp();
            } else {
                checkStoragePermission();
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

My Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.jose.updateinapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the .xml for FileProvider

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="files_root"
        path="Android/data/${applicationId}" />
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

The app that i'm attempting to install is the same but with versionCode 2 and versionName 2.0 instead of versionCode 1 and versionName 2.0

When executed this throws an error on the device: error parsing the package

Nothing comes out in the run console. And in the logcat the following errors appear:

> ```
> E/DatabaseUtils: Writing exception to parcel
>     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri
> ```
>
> content://com.jose.updateinapp.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.jose.updateinapp/files/Download/app-release.apk
>   from pid=16603, uid=10035 requires the provider be exported, or
>   grantUriPermission()
>
> ```
> Error staging apk from content URI
>     java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading androidx.core.content.FileProvider uri
> ```
>
> content://com.jose.updateinapp.provider/external_files/Android/data/com.jose.updateinapp/files/Download/app-release.apk
>   from pid=16603, uid=10035 requires the provider be exported, or
>   grantUriPermission()

Any solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry,something missed in my head.

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
<external-path
    name="external"
    path="" />
<external-files-path
    name="Download"
    path="" />
</paths>



uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                        "packgeName.provider",
                        new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), "xxx.apk"));
                intentInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
```

just try it. it worked in my project..

Comment: Changing the XML continues the same error.

What do you mean: "save your installer to context.getCacheDir ()."

Comment: It worked changing also context.getExternalFilesDir to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

Answer (score 1):

```java
private void updateApp() {
    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() + "/" + FILE_NAME));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    //setFlags change addFlags
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It worked changing also context.getExternalFilesDir to Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory